# Ubuntu x86-64: To Link buffer to memory section created in predefined address

Tags: c, linux, gcc, memory-management, ld

I want to create a 4MB buffer allocated in a predefined section of linker script. Using `ld --verbose` I got the default linker script used by gcc. I want to add a section called `.exchangeBuffer` addresable by 32-bit (virtual addresses are up to 48-bit, but I want to allocate my section in an address lower thaN 0x0000_FFFF_FFFF).

So, I imagine my buffer should be declared like this:

```
#define FOUR_MEGABYTES (4*1024*1024)
uint8_t __attribute__((section (".exchangeBuffer"))) exchange[FOUR_MEGABYTES];
```

But then default linker script, starts like this:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
          "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {

/* The scripts continue until end.... */

  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .debug_addr     0 : { *(.debug_addr) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}
```

Where and how should I place my 4MB section?

Please, note that executable is running on a 64-bit Desktop Linux compiled with their native gcc. All available information regarding this topic I found is related with embedded systems and simpler linker scripts, 32-bit processors without virtual addressing.

Thanks,

Comment: If you need control over absolute (virtual) addresses, then presumably you are going to use `-no-pie`.  And in that case, the compiler by default uses the "small" code model, in which all sections are placed in the low 2GB of the address space (see Section 3.5.1 of [the ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf)).  So it seems to me that you can forget about linker magic entirely, use `-no-pie`, just declare `uint8_t exchange[FOUR_MEGABYTES];`, and go on your merry way.

Comment: I'm curious about your motivation for doing this, however.  I can't think of very many situations where one would want to do what you describe, though I can think of several situations where one might *incorrectly think* one wanted to do this.

Comment: Another option would be to allocate your buffer using `mmap` with the `MAP_32BIT` flag.  Then you can drop `-no-pie`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I can tell you my motivation. There is a communication protocol called spacewire and RMAP operating over it (it is intended for space applications). This protocol enables communication through two nodes and one node can request to other which is the value at a given address (like a DMA). The protocol only allows addresses up to 40 bits. So is for that I know to place some buffer in a known area less addresable in less than 40-bit (32-bit also fits). Is for that I need to know also the exact address. `mmap` does not assure this. I am still invesigating the small code model.

Comment: It seems to me that the natural way to implement this would be to let your buffer be at an arbitrary address, and treat the "address" passed over the spacewire protocol as an offset into that buffer rather than as an absolute address.